# Error running test command in veins_hetvnet

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I am using Instant Veins 5.0-alpha2 i1. When executing the test procedure on veins_hetvnet, the following error is shown:

```
veins:~/src/veins_hetvnet/examples/veins_hetvnet% ./run -d -u Cmdenv | grep "HetVNetDemoApp::handleMessage"

./run: 25: exec: ../../run: not found

zsh: exit 127 ./run -d -u cmdenv |
zsh: exit 1 grep --color=auto "HetVNetDemoApp::handleMessage"
```

[Error figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c61xd.png)

Comment: You might have tried to run the project from the command line, but have only built it using the IDE. A simple `cd ~/src/veins_hetvnet` followed by `./configure` followed by `make` should fix this.

Comment: Problem solved.